# Count Records in Listing View

Tags: django, count

I have these two models:

```
class CommonVehicle(models.Model):
   year = models.ForeignKey(Year)
   series = models.ForeignKey(Series)
   engine = models.ForeignKey(Engine)
   body_style = models.ForeignKey(BodyStyle)
   ...

class Vehicle(models.Model):    
   objects = VehicleManager()
   stock_number = models.CharField(max_length=6, blank=False)
   vin = models.CharField(max_length=17, blank=False)
   common_vehicle = models.ForeignKey(CommonVehicle)
   ....
```

What I want to do is to have a count of how many times a given `CommonVehicle` object is used in the `Vehicle` class.  So far my attempts are giving me one number, which is a total of all the records.  How can I have the count being the total appearances for each `CommonVehicle`

**Update 1**
I was thinking something like this could work:

```
related_count = 0
for vehicle in vehicles:
    related_count += Vehicle.objects.filter(common_vehicle=vehicle).count()
```

Comment: @Ignacio: I've updated my question a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that the question is closely related to: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471172/django-queries-count-number-of-objects-with-fk-to-model-instance)

I should be doing this:

```
vehicles = CommonVehicle.objects.annotate(related_count=Count('vehicle')).all()
```

Then at the template where the count will be appearing:

```
{% for vehicle in vehicles %}
   ...
   {{ vehicle.related_count }}
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
somecommonvehicle.vehicle_set.count()
```

Comment: Don't mean to be much of a bother, but this answer is a bit vague

Comment: Take the "given `CommonVehicle` object" you have, access the `vehicle_set` attribute, and call the `count()` method on it.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently developing a django app whose purpose is to solve this kind problem :

https://code.google.com/p/django-cube/

The documentation is not up-to-date, as I am constantly modifying the code (for now... It's only the beginning of the project). Here is the code you would use :

```
cube = Cube(['common_vehicle'], Vehicle.objects.all(), len)
```

The you can iterate on the cube for having all the counts for all the possible `CommonVehicle`s :

```
for coords, value in cube.iteritems():
    #will print <CommonVehicule unicode representation> <count for this common vehicule>
    print coords.common_vehicule, measure
```

Or directly get the count for a `CommonVehicule` :

```
cube[Coords(common_vehicle=a_common_veh)]
```

A lot of other cool features are (will be) available ...

**PS** : the app allows to create multidimensional aggregates over a django queryset, OLAP-style ... `Cube(['common_vehicle'], Vehicle.objects.all(), len)` actually represents a cube whose dimensions are `['common_vehicle']`, base queryset is `Vehicle.objects.all()` and aggregation function is `len`.

Comment: This looks interesting.....I'll give it a try too and see...hope you finish soon :)

Comment: Yeah ! I'm actively pushing it, so it should be more stable, and more documented in the next few days ... And the syntax should be better.